# Correlation loop discarding variables

Tags: python, pandas, loops, machine-learning, correlation

I want to implement a function that computes the correlation between each pair of features. When a high correlation is found, I want to discard the feature with lowest correlation with target variable and dont evaluate it again in the loop.

I tried with the iris database as example and the following code but it does not remove the highly correlated variables from the set.

I also think that traversing twice the columns is inefficient. Thanks for any help!

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris  
iris = load_iris()
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                     columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])

X = data1.drop('target', 1)
y = pd.DataFrame(data1['target'])

#Code to later implement function
threshold = 0.5
final_vars = set()
all_vars = X.columns.values.tolist()
for var in all_vars:
    for var2 in all_vars:
        if var != var2:
            if abs(X[var].corr(X[var2])) <= threshold:
                final_vars.add(var)
                final_vars.add(var2)
            else:
                if abs(X[var].corr(y)) <= abs(X[var2].corr(y)):
                    all_vars.remove(var)
                    final_vars.add(var2)
                else: 
                    all_vars.remove(var2)
                    final_vars.add(var)
```

Comment: Q wording is confusing? Do you want to keep low correlated variables or high correlated variables. If English is not your first language (neither its mine), I suggest to *write short simple sentences ONLY*. Please, reword the Q

Comment: Thanks. For each pair of variables that are highly correlated I want to keep only the one that is most correlated with the target and do not evaluate the discarded one again in the loop.

Comment: What is the logic of keeping *most correlated* variables? If variables are highly correlated then what contribution are they making to the model? Think about it?

Comment: That is what I want to avoid. If two variables are highly correlated, I want to keep only the one with the highest correlation with the target. 
That is, given target Y, if corr(X,Z) is high and corr(X,Y)>corr(Z,Y), I keep X.

Comment: and this is exactly my point. For a given target Y, you can compare corr(x,z). However, are you sure that for the same target Y, you can also compare corr(z,y)? Furthermore, why do you want to keep an independent variable that is highly correlated with the dependent or target variable?

Comment: This is part of my pre-processing for a predictive algorithm. I want to reduce number of variables before training to reduce complexity. That is, if two features are highly correlated, I want to keep only the feature that is most related with the target variable since it would be a better predictor. I hope this make sense.

Comment: nope, it makes no sense (to me) keep  variables with (high) correlation with the target variable. Because, then your defeating the purpose of feature selection. Feature selection is essentially a dimensional reduction method. Where the idea is to keep features that are **NOT** correlated with the target variable.

Comment: Since this is supervised feature selection, a minimum threshold is specified and variables with correlation higher than this minimum threshold are discarded and variables that are less than the minimum threshold are kept for further analysis. Is this what you mean, if yes, then consider revising the Q.

Comment: If you do not discard anything in pre-processing, why would you want to keep features low correlated with the target? Since they will not have as much predictive power. Furthermore, algorithms like LASSO may select randomly between two features that are highly correlated making the model unestable. Thanks again!

Comment: Its sad to state that you've got the entire concept wrong. At this stage, I recommend to read a good statistical book on this subject, to clear your doubts. Read, [Applied Predictive Modelling](https://www.amazon.com/Applied-Predictive-Modeling-Max-Kuhn/dp/1461468485/ref=pd_sbs_14_1/146-3133577-6025156?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=1461468485&pd_rd_r=e1268b0f-0b2a-473d-90cc-91ee62d0c1a5&pd_rd_w=5lQ00&pd_rd_wg=u8WEY&pf_rd_p=12b8d3e2-e203-4b23-a8bc-68a7d2806477&pf_rd_r=RCA4N552A68Y4MAE1XFP&psc=1&refRID=RCA4N552A68Y4MAE1XFP) by Max Kuhn, simple and intuitive.